# Non-constant coefficient recurrence relation

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I am given the recurrence relation $$F(n) = F(n - 1) + \frac{1}{n}F(n - 2)$$ with $F(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $F(1) = \frac{1}{3}$ and asked to solve it.  What I have done so far is let $E(n) = n!F(n)$ and multiply by $n!$ on both sides of the equation giving 
\begin{equation*}
   \begin{split}
   n!F(n) &= n!F(n-1) + n!\frac{1}{n}F(n-2)\\
   n!F(n) &= n(n-1)!F(n-1) + (n-1)(n-2)!F(n-2)\\
   E(n) &= nE(n - 1) + (n-1)E(n - 2)\\
   E(n) - E(n - 1) &= (n - 1)\left[E(n - 1) + E(n - 2)\right]\\
   \end{split}
  \end{equation*}

Now, let $G(n) = E(n) - E(n -1)$, then $$G(n) = (n - 1)G(n - 1)$$

From here I have solved $G(n)$ to be $$G(n) = -\frac{(n - 1)!}{6}.$$ But I am having trouble getting back $F(n)$, I am not sure if my initial conditions for $G(n)$ are wrong or what.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: WA says$$F_n=\frac{-e n \Gamma (n+3)-2 e \Gamma (n+3)+5 n \Gamma
   (n+3,-1)+10 \Gamma (n+3,-1)}{6 e \Gamma (n+3)}$$

Comment: I got $$F(n) = \dfrac{1}{6}\left(\dfrac{5\cdot !(n+2)}{(n+1)!} - n-2\right)$$ where $!n$ is the subfactorial (or number of derangements).

Comment: I saw this as well but I'm not sure how to get to this place

Comment: $$E(n) - E(n - 1) = (n - 1)\left[E(n - 1) + E(n - 2)\right]$$ has a subtraction on the left but an addition on the right, so the step to $G(n)$ is wrong.

Comment: I have that $$E(n) - E(n-1) = nE(n-1) + (n-1)E(n - 2) - E(n- 1)$$ which can be rewritten as $$E(n) - E(n-1) = (n-1)[E(n - 1) + E(n - 2)]$$

Comment: The problem is in the next step. $E(n-1) + E(n-2)$ can't be rewritten as $G(n-1)$.

Comment: You are correct sir, I apologize, do you have any suggestions on the methodology for solving this problem then

Comment: I can turn it into a differential equation, but it's about 20 years since I last solved a non-trivial one of those so I'm not sure whether that's going in the right direction.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe would you mind explaining how you came to that result? I still cannot figure out how to get here.

Comment: I just meant that is what WA gave me for the answer, as opposed to the one that Dr Sonnhard Graubner got from WA. I thought it was interesting that we got answers in such different forms from the same recurrence.